# How can I safely drive a relay OR sense a switch from a single terminal?

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, relay, mosfet-driver

I am designing a device that uses an MCP23017 running at 3.3V to either check a "port" on a terminal strip as an input from a motion sensor or drive a relay/SCR/indicator from the same "port".  I'm space limited so the terminal strip needs to be dual-purpose and each "port" function will be selected in software whenever the device boots up.  It will, of course, not be an input AND output at the same time...

In "input" mode, GPA0 would be in input mode with pull-up enabled, and GPB0 would be LOW.  In "output" mode, GPA0 would be HIZ and GPB0 would control the output state.  Q3 would be 2N3904 (unless you have a better suggestion) and I need advice on a part number for Q2.

**The relay and switch on the other side of the terminal strip are just there for visualization purposes to save space.  In input mode pretend the relay isn't there, in output mode pretend the switch isn't there.  They would not be connected to the same terminals in the real world.**

Given the diagram below, can you offer some insight into the following questions?

- Is this even feasible?
- In output mode, would the 12V potential on GPA0 cause any problems over time? (It's in HIZ)
- In input mode will there be much leakage from the mosfet and will that affect sensing the input state in any way?
- Is 1N4004 the right choice for flyback diode?
- Can you recommend a P channel mosfet that is as small as possible, can handle up to 500ma and won't generate much heat?
- Are there any other issues you can spot or advice/recommendations you can give me?

I will likely add a resettable fuse on each mosfet drain as well.

[image]

Comment: What is connected to the TL32PO pin 2?

Comment: fake sensor ....

Comment: That switch is just representative.  One pin connected to GND, the other connected to GPA0 when the entire circuit is in "input" mode.

Comment: Nothing fake about it.  I've already built the same basic circuit using a low side switch with output mode as 5VDC and it works.  I think 12 will give me more versatility and I want a high side switch so I can use the internal pull-up on the MCP23017 (if possible).

Comment: So no Open collector sensors?

Comment: Switches in input mode (PIR, reed switch, high/low water level sensor, etc.)  Relays or SCRs (power control - think https://www.digital-loggers.com/iotfaqs.html) or possibly direct driving an indicator beacon like the following in output mode: https://www.banggood.com/12V-Security-Alarm-Strobe-Signal-Warning-Lamp-Blue-Red-Flashing-Light-p-921805.html

Comment: OK Make sure you use twisted pairs and shields you may need more EMI crosstalk reduction. Use 1nF to 10nF to earth ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Safely drive a relay OR sense a switch from a single terminal?

I would suggest your circuit is not "safe".

While there exists a path from the input pins to VDD through an intrinsic diode in the MCP23017, you should **NEVER** use this as a method to clamp the input. If you are doing just one input/output, then the current may be limited by the 10k Ohm resistor, but it is not a good design choice.

I'd suggest a simple change can make you schematic "safe" under all circumstances.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9Y1FS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the schematic above I've simply used Q1 to clamp the input low when you turn on the 12V supply to the relay.
The [AO3401](http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AO3401.pdf) I've shown as M1 would be a suitable choice for currents up to > 2A.

Be aware that when you are using GPA_0 as an input, that the input signal should not got above 3.3V ….and whatever that signal is, it is still impressed across the relay, so it is a low impedance input. You might want to fix that problem too.

If you are going to have multiple input/output pairs set up like this you might consider further changes. You could set up an active 3.3V clamp for the inputs.
Solving the problem of having the relay coil permanently across the signal line is somewhat more complex.

**Update:**
You could consider an approach such as this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f28ppx.png)</sup>

In the circuit above a [TL431](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf) supplies an accurate clamp voltage. Then the BAT54 (you could use BAT54C) diodes provide a clamp threshold at right about 3.3V. Even if the input signal rises to 50V this clamp would sink the current rather than the intrinsic diodes in the MCP23017.

Comment: Thanks Jack.  It would be either a switch or a relay, input or output.  Never together.  I was just trying to save space by not drawing 2 schematics where the only difference was a switch or relay connected to the same pins.  And I will have the same circuit duplicated 8 times - I'm not sure what you mean by an active 3.3v clamp...

Comment: Also, in input mode the GPA0 would be pulled high internally.  The switch on the terminal strip would pull it low.

Comment: Wouldn't D1 also clamp the output to the relay?  Seems like a direct path to ground for the mosfet

Comment: @Daemach No, D1 only clamps the GPIO pin to a low voltage. M1, when on would supply 12V to both the relay and the right hand side of R2 so there would be current flow through R2 but the GPA_0 input pin would be at about 1V.

Comment: That makes sense.  What's the improvement you would suggest for doing this x8?  And thank you for the input!

Comment: And are these acceptable for the bat54?  They seem small to me.  https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/micro-commercial-co/BAT54TW-TP/BAT54TW-TPTR-ND/819608

Comment: @Daemach Those diodes would be fine. I'll add to the answer for an x8 version.

Comment: Interesting.  What is the advantage of this approach over your first suggestion in terms of protection?  I don't care what GPA0 sees when the port is in OUTPUT mode - I just don't want to smoke the chip when I turn on a relay which the first suggestion should prevent.

Comment: @Daemach Suggestion #1 protects the input ONLY when the connector port is being used to drive a relay. #2 protects the input at ALL times, so when being used as an input it protects against overvoltage. If you can guarantee that the input NEVER goes above 3.3V then #1 is fine.

Comment: What would need to change if I ran this at 5V instead of 3.3V?  I'm finding that I don't have as much overhead left on the 3.3v bus as I thought...

Comment: In method one simply short out R4. In method two short out R4 and recalculate the clamp voltage provided by the TL431. You could use the TI calculator: http://www.ti.com/lit/zip/slvc093 or any of several online calculators such as this: http://solderer.tv/tl431-calculator/ to set your clamp voltage.  I'd suggest all you need is to change R5 to 2.7k Ohm, but you should learn how to do it.

Comment: Yep, I agree.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Would MMBT2222A-7-F be an acceptable substitute for the 2n3904?  I need SMD...

Comment: @Daemach Yes, very good choice.

Comment: Thank you for being so responsive and helpful!

Comment: Thought I should run this past you before I shipped the board off for manufacturing.  Does this look right?  https://www.screencast.com/t/day1uomf0ny

Answer (score 0):

It seems OK so far.  Initialization, intermittent cable connection or faults, not-considered.  ALthough you have not defined your max output current.  The port is rated at 25mA max and with your driver ... I assume is more than 25mA ? or 50mA? 100mA? 1A? for a 12V relay , SSR or ?

They have NCh arrays low RdsOn , not sure about Pch arrays

20V Pch 100 mΩ @ -2.5V cheaper if you buy 1k MOQ
https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/diodes-incorporated/DMG2305UX-13/DMG2305UX-13DIDKR-ND/4251545

I think you mean it to be XOR port (input  XOR Output). OR could cause contention.   ... like a R/W bus for status/control but not on the same time or same port.  Then it is simpler to ground switch for control ( low side).

The port must never see > +/-0.2V outside rails to avoid shoot-thru failure.  So the 10K series current limits to the ESD diodes on all pins , OK.

Therefore a 1N4001 relies on the 10k series to reduce the port voltage with internal Schottky diode protection. So it is OK.  BAT54 is an alternative.

### Simultaneous I/O

An alternative is to incorporate an external board wired in parallel for up to 2x 8 ports. Where the sensors (if connected) would also drive the relays using 5mA ( but not used)  This eliminates EMI from conducted coil spikes and makes radiated noise outside the box and also gives visual feedback with LED.

SMD OPTOCOUPLER isolation , driving ability , stable performance ; trigger current 5mA;   The module voltage is 5V, 9,12 V, 24V are available ; 
 [image: **strong text**]

Now you have an "Inclusive" OR Relay with Opto Isolation and external wiring terminal block (also cheap). this means the sensor can drive the 5mA opto switch and Port Rx input at the same time or the relay can be driven by the Port Tx.  It also allows you choose independent hi or lo side control **and allows you to expand to 16 ports.**

Comment: Agreed.  I do want, and am trying to achieve, XOR.  But I have no idea what your circuit represents.  The MCP23017 is controlled by ESP32.  On startup I set GPA0-7 to either HIZ (for output mode) or INPUT w/ pullup for input mode.  It would never try to be an input and output at the same time.

Comment: The bi-directional symbol is the 50 Ohm uC port Tx and with internal pullup on input. The BAT54's are additional BEMF protection.  The non-inverting driver is OFF at initalization Hi or Low -side ( your choice.)

Comment: I don't have enough free uC ports.  I need to use the MCP23017 IO expander (or similar).  This isn't a communication bus, it's simple HIGH/LOW ports.

Comment: So you are using 16 ports to control 8 I/O's

Comment: Correct.  Because I can't think of a way to do it with 8 safely or without taking up more room.  500ma per port max, but more likely 120ma @12VDC

Comment: I don't know anything about optoisolators, and I can't add the external board for space reasons.  Are you saying that the circuit should work as designed?  I'll look into optoisolators more, but if you have a schematic or part number to direct me that would be great

Comment: There are tons on Ebay , Amazon http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/images/0/06/4_channel_relay_schematic.png with different features including SMD LEDs. Overall System design is simplified as it includes typical relays and isolation for << $2/port, But they frown on shopping questions here. THat's why specs are more important